# how would i insert multiple records at a time in hibernate (using @Transactional annoation)

Tags: hibernate

i want to insert multiple record at time with hibernate

i tried with following code

service

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public boolean addTermdates(FeeTermDates feetermdates) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return theMasterDao.addTermdates(feetermdates);
    }
```

DAO

```
@Override
    public boolean addTermdates(FeeTermDates feetermdates) {
         boolean success = false;
         try {
                currentSession=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

                String stringDate=feetermdates.getDate();

                String val[]=stringDate.split(",");
                for(String date:val)
                {
                    feetermdates.setDate(date);
                    currentSession.save(feetermdates);  
                }


                success=true;
         }  
         catch (Exception e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return success;
    }
```

the above code `inserting first record and then updates with last record` as follows

```
Hibernate: insert into campus_guru_01.fee_term_dates (date, term_id, tdm_id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update campus_guru_01.fee_term_dates set date=?, term_id=? where tdm_id=?
```

i dont want to update i want to insert all records .

how to achieve it?
please any one  help me with this.

**EDIT**
even i tried with `merge`  but did not work

```
@Override
    public boolean addTermdates(FeeTermDates feetermdates) {

        int termid=feetermdates.getFeeTerms().getTermId();
        FeeTerms feeTerms=new FeeTerms();
        feeTerms.setTermId(termid);
         boolean success = false;
         try {
                currentSession=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

                String stringDate=feetermdates.getDate();
                FeeTermDates feeDate=null;
                String val[]=stringDate.split(",");
                for(String date:val)
                {
                    feeDate=new FeeTermDates();
                    feeDate.setFeeTerms(feeTerms); 
                    feeDate.setDate(date);
                    currentSession.merge(feeDate);    
                }  


                success=true;  
         }  
         catch (Exception e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return success;
    }
```

it gives following Exception

```
Hibernate: insert into campus_guru_01.fee_term_dates (date, term_id, tdm_id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update campus_guru_01.fee_term_dates set date=?, term_id=? where tdm_id=?
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object of class [com.rasvek.cg.entity.FeeTermDates] with identifier [0]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.rasvek.cg.entity.FeeTermDates#0]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:280)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:755)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:594)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:765)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:734)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:518)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1158.addTermdates(Unknown Source)
    at com.rasvek.cms.controller.MasterController.addTermdates(MasterController.java:600)
    at com.rasvek.cms.controller.MasterController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c2eff8c2.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.rasvek.cms.controller.MasterController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe737654.addTermdates(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.rasvek.cg.entity.FeeTermDates#0]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.check(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2400)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3202)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3076)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3477)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:600)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1436)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:493)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3206)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2412)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:582)
    ... 61 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the same `feetermdates` in that `for each` cycle.

I assume it save the first `feetermdates` correctly and send the insert query immediately to db, for the next value it updates the already saved one and call save on it again (which does nothing).

At the end of the method hibernate check the saved entity and see that it has an updated field and correctly issue the update query.

What you should have done is creating a new istance of the object that you wanted to save.

```
String val[]=stringDate.split(",");
Feetermdates feetermdates;
for(String date:val) {
    feetermdates = new Feetermdates();
    feetermdates.setDate(date);
    currentSession.save(feetermdates);  
}
```

**Edit:** I was wrong in saying that calling `save` for an already managed instance does nothing.

It actually trigger a `merge` which will affect performance by doing a redundant operation

Comment: when ever i set new date it will be new record  every time

Comment: No it is not, there is no new Feetermdates instruction anywhere in the method, it's an object instantiated outside of that method and passed to it as argument, so if you ever enter in that cycle you will save it multiple times